# Add custom marker to maps.me android map

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm trying to add some markers / map overlays to mapsme (maps4me, mapswithme, maps.me) android app but i haven't found any way to do it ( after digging in the code ).

Closest thing i have found would be to use Bookmarks but i haven't been able to integrate them yet.

Has any of you already tried/did it already ?

Comment: have you the solution ??
I have same problem ..

Comment: you can just import a KML